# INDEX size as bytes - PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, index, size

Is there any way to get this query to return the index size as BYTES?

```
SELECT 
    relid::regclass AS table, 
    indexrelid::regclass AS index,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(indexrelid::regclass)) AS index_size, 
    idx_tup_read, 
    idx_tup_fetch, 
    idx_scan
FROM 
    pg_stat_user_indexes 
    JOIN pg_index USING (indexrelid) 
WHERE 
    idx_scan = 0 
    AND indisunique IS FALSE;
```

Currently it shows BYTES/KB/MB and GB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `pg_size_pretty` from the query:

```
SELECT 
    relid::regclass AS table, 
    indexrelid::regclass AS index,
    pg_relation_size(indexrelid::regclass) AS index_size,
```